# VMware のゲスト OS 上のディスク容量を拡張する方法を教えて下さい

Tags: centos, filesystems, vmware

CentOS7における/dev/sda3のディスク容量拡張方法を教えて下さい。

●背景
CentOS7+Oracle19cの環境下においてOracleのcreate database文で失敗し、ora-00200等のエラーが発生し、ディスク容量が足りていないものと判断しています。

dfコマンドの結果は、以下の通りです。

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -m
ファイルシス   1M-ブロック  使用 使用可 使用% マウント位置
devtmpfs              1399     0   1399    0% /dev
tmpfs                 1414     0   1414    0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 1414    11   1404    1% /run
tmpfs                 1414     0   1414    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3            18121 17889    233   99% /
/dev/sda1              297   163    134   55% /boot
tmpfs                  283     1    283    1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                  283     0    283    0% /run/user/0
```

/dev/sda3に空きが無いことからcreate databaseコマンドに失敗したと思っています。

**追記:**
ホストマシン空き150GB超のディスク容量に対し、VMware Player上でCent OSに20GBを割り当てた際のdf結果となります。

その後、VM上でのディスク容量は、20GB→40GBに拡張しました。
/dev/sda3が10GB～20GB程度に容量を拡張することを望んでいます。

コメント欄でご指摘のコマンドを実行してみました。

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/swaps
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda2                               partition   2097148 0   -2

[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0   41943040 sda
   8        1     307200 sda1
   8        2    2097152 sda2
   8        3   18566144 sda3
  11        0    1048575 sr0
```

Comment: ディスクに空きがなければ拡張のしようが無いので、まずは何が原因で容量を食っているのかを突き止めるのが先な気がします。

Comment: ディスクは購入したサイズ以上には使えないことは理解されていると思いますが、その前提で「容量拡張」とはどのような状態・結果を望む質問なのでしょうか？

Comment: /dev/sda2 は何か使用してますか？ `cat /proc/swaps` と `cat /proc/partitions` (の `sda*` 部分) の情報があれば(そしてそこに空きがあれば), parted / gparted などでパーティション拡張可能かも？

Answer (score 0):

仮想環境におけるディスク拡張であれば、比較的簡単に行うことができます。

`/dev/sda` 全体のディスク容量は既に 40GB になっているようなので、後は未割り当ての領域を使って `/dev/sda3` のパーティションをリサイズすれば良いと思います。

いくつか方法がありますが、GParted を使うのがわかりやすくておすすめです。

---

**インストール / 起動方法:**

gparted パッケージのインストール

```
$ sudo yum install gparted
```

GParted の起動

```
$ sudo gparted
```

**操作例:**

※ パーティション操作の前には必要に応じてバックアップを取得することをおすすめします。

1. Gparted は GUI のツールになるので、上記手順でインストール後に起動。
2. 変更したい対象のパーティション (`/dev/sda3`) を選択して「リサイズ/移動」をクリック。
3. スライダーを左右に動かしてサイズを拡大する。
4. 操作をすべて終えたら最後に「適用」で変更が確定します。
5. 適用が完了したら OS を再起動して結果を確認します。

**参考:**
[「GParted」の使い方](https://pctrouble.net/software/gparted.html)

Answer (score 0):

VMwareで使用しているのなら
CentOS7はどのようにしてインストールしたのでしょう？

(あるのなら)CentOS7の ISOイメージ, あるいは別のディストリビューションの Liveディスク ISOイメージあるいは [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) をダウンロードするなどして, 準備

一時的にその ISOイメージファイルから優先で起動するよう指定すれば, 現状の仮想ディスク空間を編集可能になります。
(たぶん CD/DVD イメージからの起動とか指定できるなら, そこで指定かな？)

あとは必要に応じて GPartedでの パーティション拡張・パーティション移動など行うとよさそうです